# Differences in character encoding between Postman and Mocha API tests

Tags: api, encoding, mocha.js

I have following problem

I'm sending request to my API with names of polish cities with special polish chars like Kraków, Wrocław or Poznań

in postman with request GET /rest/city/?query=Kraków I received array of cities, everything is ok in this case.

I writing automation test for our API (node.js, mocha, supertest, chai using Visual Studio) and in this environment with GET /rest/city/?query=Kraków I received empty array of cities.
What's wrong? Do you have any problem with encoding like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solution is GET /rest/city/?query=${encodeURI(Kraków)} in visual studion